# How to find value of RV for this condtion

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The probability density function of the time to failure of an
electronic component in a copier(in hours) is $$f(x)=\exp(-x/1000)/1000$$
for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$. How
determine the number of hours at which $10$% of all components have failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ be the time to failure. We want to find the $t$ such that $\Pr(X\le t)=0.1$.

So we need to solve the equation
$$\int_0^t \frac{1}{1000}e^{-x/1000}\,dx=0.1$$
for $t$. After we integrate, we end up with the equation $e^{-t/1000}=0.9$. To solve for $t$, take the natural logarithm of both sides.

*Remark:* We wrote what you are probably expected to write. But the answer is reasonably accurate only if there is a very large number of components,  and their lifetimes are independent. All we can then conclude is that with high probability roughly $10\%$ of the components will have failed.